# Convert string field to collection to pass to subreport?

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I've got a few stand-alone reports that often need to be generated at the same time for the same pharmacies and facilities. I'd like to unite these reports under one "outer wrapper" report as subreports in detail bands.

The stand-alone reports are expecting collection parameters (and make heavy use of `$X{` and need to remain able to function independently), but I only have strings to give them. In my outer wrapper, I did try to make the `$F{pharm_id}` and `$F{fac_id}` fields collections, but they keep reverting to java.util.String, and when I manually reset them to collections and run the report, I get an error that I can't cast a string (outer wrapper) to class `java.util.Collection` (subreport input parameter).

How can I pass my `$F{pharm_id}` and `$F{fac_id}` string values to the subreports as collections?

[image]

Comment: Please edit that image. It unnecessarily takes up a lot of space.

Comment: So the string is a single item, or does it need to be split into a list to being with?

Comment: The string to be passed is a single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single string, and you need to create Collection and it to it you can do:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(new String[] {$F{pham_id}})
```

and

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(new String[] {$F{fac_id}})
```

You should be able to do this in the Parameters mappings without issue.